# How to add class if id is true in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list as follows:

```
<div id="123" className="panel"></div>
<div id="456" className="panel"></div>
<div id="789" className="panel"></div>
<div id="101" className="panel"></div>
```

So if id equals true add class open, if false remove open.

Is this possible in react, I've tried using ref but that hasn't worked.

Comment: " if id equals true" when and How id will be true?

Comment: How are you rendering this list? It sounds like you should be using a prop, not manipulating the DOM to add a class after rendering.

Comment: I have some points and each one has an id, onClick the id gets returned

Comment: Post some code. Your problem statement is not clear!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React handles making the necessary changes to the DOM based on what you render, so instead of thinking in terms of adding and removing classNames when state changes, think in terms of how your render method's output changes.

e.g. if you have some `selectedId` state which represents the currently-selected id:

```
render() {
  let {selectedId} = this.state
  return <div>
    <div id="123" className={'panel' + (selectedId === '123' ? ' open' : '')}>...</div>
    <div id="456" className={'panel' + (selectedId === '456' ? ' open' : '')}>...</div>
    ...
  </div>
}
```

---

That gets tedious to repeat if you're rendering these manually instead of based on a list of things, so you can break some of the implementation detail out into another component:

```
function Panel({children, id, open}) {
  let className = 'panel'
  if (open) className += ' open'
  return <div id={id} className={className}>{children}</div>
}

render() {
  let {selectedId} = this.state
  return <div>
    <Panel id="123" open={selectedId === '123'}>...</Panel>
    <Panel id="456" open={selectedId === '456'}>...</Panel>
    ...
  </div>
}
```